# Creating Pivot Table to new worksheet Error on table destination VBA

Tags: vba, excel

this has been asked a lot of times but may I ask where is the error here

```
Sub PivotFutureProj()

Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    wsNew.Name = "4038 future project"

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "4038 Only!R1C1:R211C87", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MONTH")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
```

having error on this part

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "4038 Only!R1C1:R211C87", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

I'm thinking because of this

```
TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R1C1"
```

Tried different approach. it's just that I'm running out of time.

I'll be grateful for every help!

Comment: I would guess and say that `"4038 Only!R1C1:R211C87"` should at least to be a valid sheet/range, i.e. `"'4038 Only'!R1C1:R211C87"`.  Similarly `wsNew.Name & "!R1C1"` would need to be `"'" & wsNew.Name & "'!R1C1"`.

Comment: got it working! Thanks!!! @YowE3K

Comment: I didn't have time last night to check if that was the only issue or not, so I'm glad that was the only problem - it's something that is easy to fix :)

Comment: I'm pretty new to VBA. you've been great @YowE3K thanks!

Comment: thanks, but what if I extract it not in pivot how about here I also have error `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, currRange) - 1 > 0 Then
                    dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsNew.Name(currCell.Value).Range("A1")
                End If`  @YowE3K

Comment: `Destination:=wsNew.Name(currCell.Value).Range("A1")` should probably be `Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")` (but I'm guessing as to what you intend by that statement, because I have no idea what your `currCell` object is - it's not mentioned in any of the code you have shown so far)

Comment: hi @YowE3K is there a way where I filter the master sheet with a criteria for example "Apple" in column G but there is no result but I want to create a new sheet with name Apple with the headers from master sheet even though there are no values.

Comment: I'm not sure.  (But I assume there would be.)  Perhaps it would be best if you submit a question, as that has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with the help of @YowE3K. Please see his comment. :)

```
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    wsNew.Name = "4038 future project"

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "'4038 Only'!R1C1:R211C87", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="'" & wsNew.Name & "'!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

validate sheet range

Comment: for futre MACROs with `PivotTable`, it's recommended to define and set your variblaes, such as `Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable` , and `Dim PvtCache As PivotCache`. You can also use `Dim PvtFld As PivotField`

Comment: hi @R3uK haha don't know where can I accept? I'll go through it later! Thanks for your assistance :D

Comment: @Anne : If I remember well, right under the downvote button of the answer, like every other answer! ;)